# DateTime field OpenErp

Tags: python, module, field, odoo

I need a field that can contain a number and text on it, like for example "6 months", i've used the `datetime` field, but it only takes a formatted date on it, and if use `integer` or `float` it takes a number, and `char` takes only a character, so how can i have an `integer` and a `char` on the same field?

Comment: I think it'd be best if you give us a little more details on what you're actually trying to achieve. Also 6 months is tricky to convert into a timdelta since one month can have 28-31 days

Comment: I need to specify a time for a product to be bought or selled, and my client, needs to specify it in a format like this, i don't know if it can be done in days format instead of months? like 45 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want currently not possible in openerp. But you can use one trick, you should use two fields one is integer for giving interval and other in char fields for giving months, days etc. You can get this example on Scheduler , ir.cron object of opener.